# Type struct storage ref[] ref is not implicitly convertible to expected type struct memory

Tags: remix, javascript, solidity-0.8.x

In my function, while using my mapping to reference to an array, I keep getting the error message below:

```
TypeError: Type struct etherGifter.CryptoGift storage ref[] storage ref is not 
implicitly convertible to expected type struct etherGifter.CryptoGift memory.
--> contracts/gifter4.sol:100:9:
|
100 | CryptoGift memory validGifts = myGifts[msg.sender];
| ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Can someone kindly help me resolve this?

Find below my snippets of my code:

```
enum Status { pendingGifting, giftGifted }

struct CryptoGift {
    Status  GiftStatus;
}

mapping(address => CryptoGift[]) private myGifts;

function viewMyGifts() public view returns ( CryptoGift[] memory ) {
    CryptoGift memory validGifts = myGifts[msg.sender];

    require( validGifts.GiftStatus != Status.giftGifted, "You have no active gifts!" );

    return myGifts[msg.sender];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In this code the problem is that you're converting a CryptoGift[] (struct's array) in a single instance of CryptoGift (struct) at this line:

```
CryptoGift memory validGifts = myGifts[msg.sender];
```

To resolve it, you can modify the code in this way:

```
function viewMyGifts() public view returns ( CryptoGift[] memory) {
        CryptoGift[] memory validGifts = myGifts[msg.sender];
        for(uint i = 0; i < validGifts.length; i++){
            // In this line you'll have access to a single instance of struct contained in `myGifts` mapping 
        }
        return myGifts[msg.sender];
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for the prompt response Kerry99. 
I do not want to access a single instance of the struct, but rather a list of ALL the instances stored in the array!

Comment: Therefore don't make the for cycle on an CryptoGift[] array. Please note, if you don't iterate the single instances contained in an array, you cannot access to each variable declared in the struct.

Comment: Thanks Kerry99, the desired return result is an array that I can later iterate through on the front end UI.