# How to write a getter function for an array of structs? "storage ref[] storage ref is not implicitly convertible to expected type uint256[]"

Tags: solidity, contract-development, remix, contract-design

I'm developing an app that allows user to make bets against each other.
In order to get some useful web-UI info, i need to write a getter function for an array of structs.

Simplified version of my code to get the point across:

```
struct UserStruct {
    uint256 betAmount;
    uint256 matchId;}

mapping(address => UserStruct[]) public userStructs;

function appendUserBet( uint256 eventNumber) public payable{
    UserStruct memory userStruct = UserStruct(msg.value, eventNumber);
    userStructs[msg.sender].push(userStruct);}

function userStructLookUp(uint eventNumber, address userId) public view returns (UserStruct memory){   
        uint index = userStructs[userId].length;
        for (uint i = 0; i < index; i++) {
            if (userStructs[userId][i].matchId == eventNumber) {
                return userStructs[userId][i];}}}
```

My `userStructs` has two keys - an `address` and an `event id`, which my current version of a getter function can work with, given I provide it with required args.

What I need though is a function that would provide me with an array of structs for a particular user when i provide said function with a user address. So i supposed it would be like this:

```
    function userMatchesLookUp(address userId ) public view returns(uint256[] memory){
        return userStructs[userId];}
```

But it doesn't compile because i try to assign the return to the wrong type `storage ref[] storage ref is not implicitly convertible to expected type uint256[]`, but which is the correct?. A similar question was asked here [[Similar question]](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/122831/type-struct-storage-ref-ref-is-not-implicitly-convertible-to-expected-type-str) but there was no solution to the problem. Can you please tell me where i went wrong?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is that you're retrieving inside `userMatchesLookUp()` function an uint256 array and you're returning entire array of struct.
I suggest you to return entire array of struct because in this way you can retrieve all values inside it, like: betAmount and matchId for each match.

I adjusted your smart contract in this way:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract Test {
    struct UserStruct {
        uint256 betAmount;
        uint256 matchId;
    }

    mapping(address => UserStruct[]) public userStructs;

    function appendUserBet( uint256 eventNumber) public payable{
        UserStruct memory userStruct = UserStruct(msg.value, eventNumber);
        userStructs[msg.sender].push(userStruct);
    }

    function userStructLookUp(uint eventNumber, address userId) public view returns (UserStruct memory){   
        uint index = userStructs[userId].length;
        for (uint i = 0; i < index; i++) {
            if (userStructs[userId][i].matchId == eventNumber) {
                return userStructs[userId][i];
            }
        }
    }

    // NOTE: I changed your return object with struct array in signature function
    function userMatchesLookUp(address userId) public view returns(UserStruct[] memory){
        return userStructs[userId];
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you must add age.rhref before adding the compile.json or else function will override `uint256 eventNumber` always make sure to reference ethereum.api.null in docs. or else this image will show what i meant [ethereum ui](https://images.app.goo.gl/3z98cNnC8M1nricZ7)